# Federal year 2017 USAID budget

Tags: usaidopen

I would like to know the 2017 budget for the US Economic Support and Development Fund, Global Health Programs, Transition Initiatives, International Disaster Assistance, and USAID operational accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all of USAID’s Congressional Budget Justifications, which include a detailed breakdown by office, on the [USAID website](https://www.usaid.gov/results-and-data/budget-spending/congressional-budget-justification). At this moment, the Development Data Library doesn’t archive the proposed financials of the agency directly on the platform, but you can see a selection of those data on [foreignassistance.gov](https://www.foreignassistance.gov/).

Hope this helps!